# iPhone : Creating PDF file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to create PDF file which contains images and text.

The text length for PDF is not sure.

So How do I determine the number of pages the PDF will going to create ?

Comment: why do you need to know the number of pages will create ? is it a requisite of your PDF library or is it needed for storage or transmission ? simplest way: generate your pdf and count the pages :)

Comment: @Devang: +1 for a good question mate!

Comment: Check this two links : http://www.raywenderlich.com/6581/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1, http://www.raywenderlich.com/6818/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2